# Building dictool_aosp.jar from source

Tags: android, dictionary, build, keyboard, android-source

I couldn't be able to build dictool_aosp.jar. I downloaded the aosp source from the repository then run the following commands:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_flo-userdebug
make -j3
make dictool_aosp
```

But, I got the following error:

```
including ./system/vold/Android.mk ...
including ./tools/external/fat32lib/Android.mk ...

make: *** No rule to make target `dictool_aosp'.  Stop.

#### make failed to build some targets (01:02 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Can you please guide me on how to build the jar file?

I have also tried to build from the directory using `mm` and `mma` and got the following result:

```
$ cd packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/tools/dicttool/
$ mma
...
including ./tools/external/fat32lib/Android.mk ...
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE flo
make: Entering directory `/android-repo'
make: Nothing to be done for `all_modules'.
make: Leaving directory `/android-repo'

#### make completed successfully (24 seconds) ####

$ mm
...
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE flo
make: Entering directory `/android-repo'
make: *** No rule to make target `/temp/out/dist/android-repo/host/linux-x86/framework/junit.jar', needed by `/temp/out/dist/android-repo/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/dicttool_aosp_intermediates/javalib.jar'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/android-repo'
```

Although `mma` succeeded there is **no** `jar` file in the output directory.

Comment: execute make dicttool_aosp (double letter 't') not dictool_aosp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you receive this error when you run `make dictool_aosp`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dictool_aosp'.  Stop.
```

Means there is **no** make target named `dictool_aosp`.

You could try to build `dictool_aosp` by checking the `Android.mk` of that package. Look if there is a `LOCAL_MODULE` definition. If there is one you can  use this one for your make call. If not you can add that or simply run `mm` on top of your project directory you want to build.

Some useful hints:

- You can see all make targets with: `make modules`
- You can build a subproject with `mm` (builds all of the modules in the current directory) or use `mma` (builds all of the modules in the current directory **with** dependencies)

Comment: Apparently, `dictool_aosp` doesn't appear in the result of `make modules` even though the `Android.mk` file has `LOCAL_MODULE := dictool_aosp`. Anyways, I run both `mma` and `mm` in the `dictool` directory and failed to generate `jar` file. I have updated my question with the result. Thanks.

Comment: @MatiBekuma the error message of "mm" indicates that you are missing junit. Does your AOSP include it ? Have you run "make" before "mm" without an error ?

Comment: Sorry for my typo, it should be `make dicttool_aosp` (with double tt). I have run this command from the source (branch `android-5.0.0_r1.0.1`)  with no issue.